# Why is the command Add-ADGroupMember no longer working with the parameter -Member?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Command Ran:

```
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "Group Name" -Member UserName
```

Works fine with:

```
Major Minor Build Revision
----- ----- ----- --------
5 1 14409 1005
```

Does not work now with:

```
Major Minor Build Revision
----- ----- ----- --------
5 1 17134 228
```

Error Displayed:

> Add-ADGroupMember : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'Member' is ambiguous.

I can't find anything on Microsofts website stating that they made a change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PowerShell supports partial parameter names](https://workingsysadmin.com/quick-tip-powershell-supports-partial-parameter-names/), as long as they are unambiguous.

So even though `-Member` was never a parameter, it was interpreted to be `-Members` since that was the only parameter that started with "Member".

The change that broke this is the addition of the `MemberTimeToLive` parameter to the [`Add-ADGroupMembers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/add-adgroupmember) cmdlet. So now `-Member` can either match to `-Members` or `-MemberTimeToLive`. It's not going to decide for you, so you get the error.

Comment: Great information and it answers the question, thanks. This was just really bugging me.

Answer (score 3):

The param is plural, you need to use:

```
Add-ADGroupMembers -Identity "Group Name" -Members samaccountname
```

As far as I know this has always been the case with powershell 5+.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/add-adgroupmember?view=win10-ps

Comment: As you can see in my post the param was not plural and ran correctly in ver 5. I ran it in multiple scripts for over a year. The only thing that changed was the Build and Revision.

Comment: @Lander7 The only cmdlet that I know of that would allow this is `Add-LocalGroupMember`, you can use `-Member` there. All powershell versions are "forwards" compatible so it seems highly unlikely that this feature would just be removed. Do you have any machines that are using that older build?

Comment: @Lander7 Please look at the answer from Gabriel. Beautiful explanation.